# Get values from multiple arrays, each one array retrieved by variable

Tags: php, arrays

here is what I'm struggling with.

I have following array:

```
Array
(
    [id] => item1
    [name] => item2
    [code] => item3
    [active] => item4
    [new] => item5
    [average] => item6
    [count] => item7
)
```

To print it i use `print_r($item);`

I know how to get values from this one array and input them in .xml file. The code I'm obligated to use is:

```
$stringData = '
<start>
<item1>'.$items["key1"].'</item1>
<item2>'.$items["key2"].'</item2>
<item3>'.$items["key3"].'</item3>
<item4>'.$items["key4"].'</item4>
<item5>'.$items["key5"].'</item5>
<item6>'.$items["key6"].'</item6>
<item7>'.$items["key7"].'</item7>
</start>';
```

The content of the array (i.e. `print_r($item);`), however, depends on a variable. Let's name it `$var`

What I need to do is:

1. Connect to my database and take all `$var` values - know how to do this
2. Call the array - know how to do this
3. What I don't know how to do is - loop through all arrays and take their values as stated above

I've tried

```
foreach($item as $items) {<start>....</start>}
```

but no luck

Code for calling the array:

```
$cou = $cou_s->findOneByCode($var);
$item = $module->getSo($cou);
```

Any help appreciated.

Full code here - `http://pastebin.com/CDJczAVr`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`http://pastebin.com/CDJczAVr` - confirmed working. The problem was I had to put `$html->clear();` after the  `while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { }` closing tag.

Answer (score 0):

Check the docs on the [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) function. You want the array first, the name of each item after the `as`.

```
foreach($items as $item) {<start>....</start>}
```

Comment: My bad. The array is `$item` and in the loop I have `$items` - not working (I've corrected the question)

Comment: You say you didn't have any luck with the foreach loop. What did you get vs what you expected?

Comment: Get no values inserted and end after first loop

Comment: Could you provide a var_dump of the items array?

Comment: Here is the var_dump:

`array(9) {
  ["id"]=>
  int(35)
  ["name"]=>
  string(6) "Poland"
  ["code"]=>
  string(2) "PL"
  ["active_citizens"]=>
  int(8388)
  ["new_citizens_today"]=>
  int(60)
  ["average_citizen_level"]=>
  int(30)
  ["online_now"]=>
  int(342)
  ["region_count"]=>
  int(24)` 

and more data that I don't need (subarrays and so on).

Comment: First, remove line 62, you don't need to open the file every time you want to write to it, it's already open.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41902/discussion-between-matt-wilson-and-milenmk)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this:

```php
$stringData .= '<start>';

foreach ($items as $key => $item) {
    $stringData .= '<'. $key .'>' . $item . '</'. $key .'>';
}

$stringData .= '</start>';
```

**EDIT**:
I assumed that keys of the array are the names of the elements in the .xml. If so, the code above should be fine.

Comment: I get the idea, but I don't need `echo`. The contect between `$stringData = ' ... ';` is then inserted in xml file. So echo not working for my purpose.

Comment: The numbers are just to get the idea. In fact there are words - see full code `http://pastebin.com/CDJczAVr`

Comment: latest edit works, but only inserts the data for the first loop i.e. first value of $cou_code - there are 70 in total.

Comment: Ok, then move this code: `$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file"); fwrite($fh, $stringData);` outside the `while` loop and concatenate the string on every loop iteration: like this `$stringData .= '<start>';` intead of this `$stringData = '<start>';`